# Is the javascript browser tool at printfriendly.com secure for my browser

Tags: windows, web-browser, javascript

I use Win Xp Home with SP3 and am pretty aware of security problems. I use Palemoon 12.1, a version of Firefox optimized for windows.

I usually use printfriendly bookmarklet to create printable pages or to print pdf from web:

I was curious to test it on the [Anubis](https://anubis.iseclab.org/index.php?action=home) executable checker and I know of these possible problems:

- Performs File Modification and Destruction: The executable modifies and destructs files which are not temporary.
- Changes security settings of Internet Explorer: This system alteration could seriously affect safety surfing the World Wide Web.
- Performs Registry Activities: The executable creates and/or modifies registry entries.

In any case my doubt is especially that this javascript command uses iexplorer to work and not my main browser with limitated account: is this possible?

May it be unsafe for base security of my account and for my PC?

Comment: I found an useful, free and user-friendly on line tool to judge the matter: it is http://wepawet.iseclab.org/

Comment: Every URL you use it on is sent to the server. You download a piece of javascript from then and run it each time, it's impossible to audit this as the javascript could change at any time..

Answer (score 2):

Read this report carefully and don't worry about it. This isn't on what URL does with iexplore.exe (IE) but what IE does with typed URL. Every website will bring you similar report ([e.g. report for google.com](http://anubis.iseclab.org/?action=result&task_id=1dc8232845fb496e4b5c38eab785e68fc&format=html)).

I recommend you to check that URL with services that analyze URLs, like [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/#url).